# Facebook API forget offline access key

Tags: facebook

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now and I can't seem to get it to work.

I want my website's users to link their facebook account with my website. So they can see their stream e.t.c on my site.

All of this is working fine. But now I want to give the users an option of being able to disconnect their facebook account from my site.

In order to do this, all I do is delete the offline authentication key that I have with me. But the next time, the user tries to reconnect their facebook, I get an error which says "An error has occured"

The user has deleted permissions on my end but has not revoked access to my app on facebook. This is when the issue occurs. Is there a way for me to revoke access through the api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the solution to my problem was to send a DELETE request to /user_id/permissions with the access_token.

This deletes all permissions for the app.

Answer (score 0):

You you delete the access token on your end then you need to get a new one through the API when they want to "reconnect".

Also be aware that the offline_access permission is going away:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

So this is something you're going to need to be doing in the future anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the deprecation of the offline_access token.

And as far as my current issue is concerned, I found that all i needed to do was send a DELETE request to /user_id/permissions with the access_token.